# Ehcache statistics thread not getting timeout

Tags: java, ehcache

We are using ehcache 2.7 version in our application. As part of performance test, we observed that there are more than 8000 threads in waiting state. These all threads were statistics threads created by ehcache. Is there any configuration which can be used to keep this thread count limited. We can't upgrade to newer version at this point of time. Please suggest.

Comment: Can you post a thread dump? May be not all 8000 threads, just a dozen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening due to the way ehcache CacheManager works. In the ehcache 2.7 version, the number statistics threads created are equal to the number of processors per CacheManager. As we had 32 processor machine and more than 200 cache managers this number grew to 8000. The following two issues which we are planning to fix - 
1. Upgrade the ehcache to newer version where it creates only 1 statistics thread per cache manager.
2. Use single cache manager for multiple identical caches.
3. Destroy the cache manager if cache is flushed.

Thanks!